# Convert contents of an HTML file to a string

Tags: javascript, html, file-upload

I'd like to know how to input a .html file to a browser, which then takes the contents of said .html file and converts it into one big string so that I can pass it into a JavaScript function to parse it. As I understand it, HTML5 implemented a file API but I'm not entirely sure if it's capable of doing what I want, or how to really use it for all that matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following :

```
$filename = "yourhtmlfile.html";
$handle = fopen($filename, "r");
// Retrieve the content of HTML file, and stocks it into $contents var
$contents = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
fclose($handle);
```

Comment: Make sure you've checked the headers of the file (and some others file controls). It can be a security threat if the uploaded file contains some malicious code.